# Is there any way to find out the AD in which a pod is deployed?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

1. I have deployed a pod in K8 cluster.
2. Now i wish to know the Availablity domain in which the Pod is deployed.
3. I have not used any node affinity, can I find this out?

Comment: Availability domain ? do you mean the zone in which it is deployed ? For Ex - europe-west1-a

Comment: Yes, A region can have multiple Availaibility domains/zones. I want to find out which zone is my pod part of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Pod` itself is scheduled on a `Node`. The `Node` is the actual (virtual) machine that is deployed into a special availability zone.

The availability zone of a node can usually be read from the labels `topology.kubernetes.io/zone` (new), or `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` (old)

So to find out in which availability zone your pod is, you'll have to find out on which node it was scheduled and then check that node for those labels.

You can do it like this:

```
kubectl get node -o wide
```

Copy the name of the node and then paste it into the following command:

```
kubectl describe node <node-name>
```

Under the section `labels`, you can then check for the labels described above to find out in which availability zone the node lives and hence - where your pod was scheduled.

Comment: Thanks for answering . Can you suggest any other way as describing a node is not allowed in my case.

Comment: Sure thing. Hm I dont think there is any other way. If you can not get any information about the node, you will most likely not get any info about the zone. But I am wondering: Why do you need that info if you don't have access to the node?

Comment: my environment does not allow me to get any information about the node, so i was wondering if there exist any work around for that. I was bit skeptical about the possibility, but you cleared it.Thank you.